# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que la función al poner S o N se repita nuevamente la calculadora?

Tags: javascript, html, bucle-for, function, switch

Buen día me gustaría saber como podría ser que en la función repetición al momento de poner "s" se volviera a ejecutar el código en volver a preguntar todo en un inicio, ya que se ejecuta todo hasta en el momento de apretar el botón click, nada mas me sale el mensaje de si desea hacerlo de nuevo s/n y al momento de poner s no me vuelve a ejecutar nada , les agradecería mucho la ayuda por favor y muchas gracias en verdad.

```
<body>
    <h1>Calculadora con estructura de decision</h1>
    <button onclick="calculadora()"> click</button>
    <script>
    let varA,varB,varC,resultado;
    let s, n;
    let i=1;
    let res ;
    res =parseFloat(prompt("cuantas veces desea repetir"));
for( i ; i<=res ; i++ ) {
        varA=parseFloat(prompt("introdusca un numero"));
        varB=parseFloat(prompt("introdusca otro numero"));
        varC=parseFloat(prompt("introdusca el ultimo numero"));
        signo=prompt("ponga un signo");
        
       
        switch(signo) {
            case '+':
            resultado=(varA+varB+varC);
            alert("este es el resultado " + resultado);
            
            break;
            case '-':
            resultado=(varA-varB-varC);
            alert("este es el resultado " + resultado);
            break;
            case '*':
            resultado=(varA*varB*varC);
            alert("este es el resultado " + resultado);
            break;
            case '/':
            resultado=(varA/varB/varC);
            alert("este es el resultado " + resultado);
            break;
            default:
             }   
   
            }

function repetir(){
    
    let res=parseFloat(prompt("desea hacerlo de nuevo s/n"));
            let s, n;
            if(res == s){
                varA=parseFloat(prompt("introdusca un numero"));
                varB=parseFloat(prompt("introdusca otro numero"));
                varC=parseFloat(prompt("introdusca el ultimo numero"));
                signo=prompt("ponga un signo");
                }else
                if(res == n){
                    alert("bye");
                }
            }
    

    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modifiqué tu código un poco, quité el `for` ya que no tenía sentido preguntar cuantas veces quieres repetir, es mejor hacerlo como te lo estoy dejando

como verás hay un while que se ejecuta hasta que reciba un valor false, el cual ocurre cuando tu pones **n** en la pregunta `'¿desea hacerlo de nuevo?'`

```
<body>
    <h1>Calculadora con estructura de decision</h1>
    <button onclick="calculadora()"> click</button>
    <script>
    let varA,varB,varC,resultado;
    let s, n;
    let i=1;
        //se va a repetir hasta que se tenga un valor false
        while(repetir){tarea()}

        //esta función va a mantener la tarea hasta que pongas 'n'
            function repetir(){    
    let res=parseFloat(prompt("desea hacerlo de nuevo s/n"));
            let s, n;
            if(res == s){
                tarea();
                return true
                }else
                if(res == n){
                    alert("bye");
                    return false
                }
            } 
    
   function tarea(){
        varA=parseFloat(prompt("introduzca un numero"));
        varB=parseFloat(prompt("introduzca otro numero"));
        varC=parseFloat(prompt("introduzca el último número"));
        signo=prompt("ponga un signo");
     
        switch(signo) {
            case '+':
            resultado=(varA+varB+varC);
            alert("este es el resultado " + resultado);
            
            break;
            case '-':
            resultado=(varA-varB-varC);
            alert("este es el resultado " + resultado);
            break;
            case '*':
            resultado=(varA*varB*varC);
            alert("este es el resultado " + resultado);
            break;
            case '/':
            resultado=(varA/varB/varC);
            alert("este es el resultado " + resultado);
            break;
            default:
             }   
         }

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: en verdad muchas gracias por la ayuda, te lo agradezco mucho :,)

Comment: de nada, aun asi puedes modificar el código para ajustarlo a tu tarea